# Application with http request running in emulator but not on the phone

Tags: android, android-studio

As said in title, I have problem running my simple app which makes http request on my phone. On emulator it works perfectly, but on phone it can't download the string required.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;

public String uzmiLokacije()
{
    String url_all_products = "http://www.parkingpmf.co.nf/db_get_all.php";
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    String res = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_all_products);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        //String res = "";

        while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            res = res + line;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        return res;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(
    ){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ans = uzmiLokacije();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ans, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Any hints why is this happening?
I added this in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

P.s. I'm working with Android Studio

Comment: Have you tried accessing that page in a Web browser on this device? Also, you need to move this network I/O to a background thread, as you may be crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: I have tried opening in browser and yes it works. Can you explain how to do it, because I didn't do anything with background threads till now?
I will try catching that exception now

Comment: Please provide some more information for us to help you, like your phone, it's android version, etc...

Comment: Android version on the phone is 4.2.2
Here is my gradle part regarding versions:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exampleapp.luka.novi"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

Comment: Edit: I caught NetworkOnMainThreadException exception. Now what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0):

Android forbids loading data from the internet in the main thread, because it will make the app laggy with a slow connection. You can write your own worker thread or you can use the one provided by android itself.

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

(Example taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html))

As you can see, this example sets the text of a TextView to a text loaded from the internet. You have to change the code in the Methods `onResponse` and `onErrorResponse` to implement your own logic.